# Share data between methods

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, instance-variables, attr-accessor

I have this module, which gets included in a class:

```
module MyModule

    def self.included base
        base.extend ClassMethods
    end

    module ClassMethods
        def my_module_method data
            include MyModule::InstanceMethods

            after_save :my_module_process

            attr_accessor :shared_data
            shared_data = data
            # instance_variable_set :@shared_data, data
        end
    end

    module InstanceMethods

        private

        def my_module_process
            raise self.shared_data.inspect
            # raise instance_variable_get(:@shared_data).inspect
        end

    end

end
```

I want to use the `data` (parameter) passed to `my_module_method` within `my_module_process`. I've used `attr_accessor` as well as instance variables, but either of them return `nil`.

Comment: DO you think It might be worth doing in the class first, before you extract the logic into a module? Before you go into including and extending, I think it would be wise to take a step back and just view these in the context of the class.  As of right now, It is had to tell what goals you want to achieve.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you're using rails, your module can be greatly simplified by making it a AS::Concern

```
module MyModule
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  included do
    # after_save :my_module_process # or whatever
    cattr_accessor :shared_data
  end

  module ClassMethods
    def my_module_method(data)
      self.shared_data = data
    end
  end

  def my_module_process
    "I got this shared data: #{self.class.shared_data}"
  end
end
```

The key points here are:

- `cattr_accessor`, which is similar to `attr_accessor`, but defines class-level methods
- `self.class.shared_data` to access that class-level data from the instances.

Usage:

```
class Foo
  include MyModule
end

f = Foo.new
f.my_module_process # => "I got this shared data: "
Foo.my_module_method({foo: 'bar'})
f.my_module_process # => "I got this shared data: {:foo=>\"bar\"}"
```

---

> I've used attr_accessor as well as instance variables, but either of them return nil.

In ruby, it is super-important to know what is `self` at any given moment. This is what defines the methods and instance variables available to you. As an exercise, I offer you to find out, why `user.name` returns nil here (and how to fix it).

```
class User
  @name = 'Joe'

  def name
    @name
  end
end

user = User.new
user.name # => nil
```